# d3.js graphics not showing in Jupyter notebook output HTML

Tags: d3.js, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using a d3.js visualisation that works perfectly in the Jupyter notebook with the d3 cell magic. However, when I output the notebook to html, I just get a blank space.

Below is the code. Does anyone know how to make this work with the html output? Ideally I would like the chart to remain interactive.

```
%%d3 4.1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>

<svg width="760" height="760"></svg>

<script>


 require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"
     }
 });

  require(["d3"], function(d3) 
{

   console.log(d3);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 20,
    diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
    .domain([-4, 4]);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .padding(2);

d3.json("output.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: can you please share the python code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The data that you are use to input here:

```
d3.json("output.json", function(error, root) {if (error) throw error;"
```

Are you sure that is on the right path?
For me, I got a similar problem and was because the input data path was incorrect.